# Why does my jquery form validation not work for IE7? It works in FF, Opera, Safari, etc

Tags: jquery, validation, firefox, forms, internet-explorer-7

I recently used jquery and the form validation plugin on a form we're testing at our community college:

- [www.mchenry.edu/parentorientation](http://www.mchenry.edu/parentorientation)

Right off the bat, (if viewed with FF, Opera, Safari, etc.) when you click submit w/o entering any values, you get some nice error messages in the form, the intended effect. However, if you're using IE7, when you click submit you get the server-side validation that our backend developer is partial to. Why does IE7 ignore the jquery validation and jump to the server-side validation? Can I do anything to get IE to behave or am I stuck with what I have?

Thanks for whatever insight you can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 51

> }, //end messages

Remove comma.

And use [IE Debug Bar](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/HomePage).

Try it with a higher version of the jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0, it is working with IE7 and 8.

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is 2 years old but I found it via google so maybe someone else will.

The problem [mentioned by fozylet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5933640/94928) has been fixed in jQuery Validation plugin version 1.9.0
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

name attribute is not required for it to work anymore. I am using spring for my forms so actually it wasn't possible to specify the name attribute. Also stray commas doesn't stop the form validation working now either.

better late than never...

Comment: Thanks, I was using an older version. Fixed my XP IE8 issues up nicely!

Comment: Great, this fixes it for me too.  Was using 1.8.

Answer (score 4):

Another important thing to note while using jQuery validation plugin on IE is this:

**ID** and **Name** must be specified for the *elements* you are validating as well as for the *form* and *submit* button. While FF and Chrome works without these, IE doesn't.

The tab-out validation does work without the name, but not the form submit validation.